# foreachActive functionality for Vector

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Can someone help me to understand the usage of "foreachActive"  function introduced for the Vectors.

I am trying to understand its usage in MultivariateOnlineSummarizer class for summary statistics.

```
sample.foreachActive { (index, value) =>
  if (value != 0.0) {
    if (currMax(index) < value) {
      currMax(index) = value
    }
    if (currMin(index) > value) {
      currMin(index) = value
    }

    val prevMean = currMean(index)
    val diff = value - prevMean
    currMean(index) = prevMean + diff / (nnz(index) + 1.0)
    currM2n(index) += (value - currMean(index)) * diff
    currM2(index) += value * value
    currL1(index) += math.abs(value)

    nnz(index) += 1.0
  }
}
```

Comment: From the doc: "Applies a function f to all the active elements of dense and sparse vector." What exactly is unclear to you in this description?

Comment: I wanted to understand how summary is calculated and the underlying working of algorithm. Is there any source of reference to understand this? Thanks.

Comment: Seems like simply updating mean, max, min, and number of non-zero items (nnz) on each occurrence of a non-zero element (`if value != 0.0`). If your question is on the details of the logic, most probably, [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 kinds of Vectors in spark DenseVector & SparseVector

For DenseVector all elements are active, so foreachActive effectively becomes foreach

```
  private[spark] override def foreachActive(f: (Int, Double) => Unit) = {
    var i = 0
    val localValuesSize = values.size
    val localValues = values

    while (i < localValuesSize) {
      f(i, localValues(i))
      i += 1
    }
  }
```

SparseVector can have inactive elements, which should be skipped either manually in foreach, or using foreachActive, which does it under the hood

```
  private[spark] override def foreachActive(f: (Int, Double) => Unit) = {
    var i = 0
    val localValuesSize = values.size
    val localIndices = indices
    val localValues = values

    while (i < localValuesSize) {
      f(localIndices(i), localValues(i))
      i += 1
    }
  }
```

So this is effectively foreach function for Vectors, which filters out only active elements, regardless of Vector implementation.

Comment: Anyone know why it's `private`? Sure would be useful in custom code.